# Problem setting the name of a file when using the Google Drive REST API for resumable uploads

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api

```
async function createResumableSession(filePath, authClient){
try {
  const fileStats = await statsAsync(filePath);
  const fileSize = fileStats.size;

  const postResult = await new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
    request({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable',
            followAllRedirects: true,
            headers: {
              Authorization: "Bearer " + authClient.credentials.access_token,
              "X-Upload-Content-Length": `${fileSize}`,
              "Content-Length": "0",
              "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
             },
            body:JSON.stringify({
              title: "myfile.backup"
            })
          }, function (error, response) {
                if (error) 
                    return reject(error);

                resolve({
                    statusCode: response.statusCode,
                    location: response.headers.location,
                    body: response.body
                });
            })
        })

        return {
            postResult,
            fileSize
        }
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
}
```

I have this function to create a resumable upload on the Google Drive API, its creating the session correctly but I cant set the file name, after the upload is completed the file name always end as "untitled"

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

In your script, from the endpoint of `https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable`, it is found that you are using Drive API v3. In this case, in order to set the filename, it is required to use the property of `name`. In your script, `title` is used. In this case, it is for Drive API v2. So please modify as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
title: "myfile.backup"
```

To:

```
name: "myfile.backup"
```

#### Reference:

- [Files: create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create)

If this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize.

### Added:

As a simple sample script, I added a sample script. In this sample script, a text file is uploaded using the resumable upload. In this case, the file is uploaded as the filename of "sample". And you can see the text of `foo` in the uploaded file.

#### Sample script:

```
const request = require('request');
const accessToken = "###";  // Please set your access token.

request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=resumable',
  headers: {
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({name: "sample", mimeType: "text/plain"})
}, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
  }
  request({
    method: 'PUT',
    url: res.headers.location,
    headers: {"Content-Range": "bytes 0-2/3"},
    body: Buffer.from("foo")
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    console.log(res.statusCode)
    console.log(res.body)
  });
});
```

- Using the property of `name`, the metadata of file has the filename of `sample`.

But unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand about your current issue. So can I ask you about the detail information about `the problem persists`? And in order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the detail flow and whole script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information. By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I tried what you proposed and the problem persists

Comment: @Christian Marlon Martins Barbo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I added a simple sample script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Have you tried what @Tanaike suggested of changing titlte for name in your body request? If so, does it keep addding the file with the name ```untitled```? [Check out the reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create#request-body) for more info about creating files and setting their names.

Comment: @Tanaike, your script works because you send all the data in just one "PUT", i tried that way before and it worked like in your script , but when i try to send multiple chunks of data (multiple PUTs), it doesnt work. thx anyway

Comment: @MateoRandwolf, yes i tried changing  "title" for  "name" and still getting untitled

Comment: @Christian Marlon Martins Barbo Thank you for replying. I cannot understand about `when i try to send multiple chunks of data, it doesnt work`. Because the metadata of file is set at the initial request. Even when there are multiple chunks, when 1st request is not correct, the metadata is not set correctly. So in order to correctly understand about your current situation, can you provide the detail flow and whole script for replicating your issue? Of course, please remove your personal information. By this, I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Mateo Randwolf Thank you for your support. I proposed for OP to provide the whole script without the personal information. By this, I thought that the reason of issue might be found.

Comment: @ChristianMarlonMartinsBarbo have you tried taking a look at [batch requests](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch#details) to make multiple CRUD operations? That might work for your case. Let me know if it does/doesn't

Comment: thx to all responses, i got it working finnaly, it was a problema with the byte offset when sending chunks of data